# Set minimum order quantity by category (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have different product categories on my store. I have a "nettoyage" category that i'd like to allow clients to order ONLY if the number of "nettoyage" items in the cart is > 3 .

Right now, i've set up the default quantity to 3 and don't allow the user to go below on product pages. But what i'd like is to allow them to add 1 of each for example and allow them to order as long as the number of "nettoyage" products in the cart is > 3. How can i refactor this code to do this ?

Right now, i have the following code in my functions.php :

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'bloomer_woocommerce_quantity_changes', 10, 2);

function bloomer_woocommerce_quantity_changes($args, $product)
{

    if (!is_cart()) {
        if (is_singular('product') && (has_term('nettoyage', 'product_cat'))) {

            $args['input_value'] = 3; // Start from this value (default = 1)
            $args['max_value'] = 10; // Max quantity (default = -1)
            $args['min_value'] = 3; // Min quantity (default = 0)
            $args['step'] = 1; // Increment/decrement by this value (default = 1)

        }
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'min_qty_filter_callback', 20, 2);
function min_qty_filter_callback($args, $product)
{
    $categories = array('Noten'); // The targeted product category(ies)
    $min_qty    = 3; // The minimum product quantity

    $product_id = $product->is_type('simple') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if (has_term($categories, 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
        $args['min_value'] = $min_qty;
    }
    return $args;
}

// On shop and archives pages
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'min_qty_loop_add_to_cart_args', 10, 2);
function min_qty_loop_add_to_cart_args($args, $product)
{
    $categories = array('nettoyage'); // The targeted product category
    $min_qty    = 3; // The minimum product quantity

    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    if (has_term($categories, 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
        $args['quantity'] = $min_qty;
    }
    return $args;
}

add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_min_item_required_qty');
function wc_min_item_required_qty()
{
    $categories    = array('nettoyage'); // The targeted product category
    $min_item_qty  = 3; // Minimum Qty required (for each item)
    $display_error = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key) {
        $item_quantity = $cart_item['quantity']; // Cart item quantity
        $product_id    = $cart_item['product_id']; // The product ID

        // For cart items remaining to "Noten" producct category
        if (has_term($categories, 'product_cat', $product_id) && $item_quantity < $min_item_qty) {
            wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

            // Add an error notice (and avoid checkout).
            wc_add_notice(sprintf("Le service livraison nettoyage n'est valable qu'à partir de %s paires!", $min_item_qty, $item_quantity), 'error');
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly found the solution. For those interested, here is the custom function :

```php
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'custom_set_min_total');
function custom_set_min_total()
{
    if (is_cart() || is_checkout()) {

        global $woocommerce, $product;
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product) :
            $minimum_cart_product_total = 3;

            if (has_term('nettoyage', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'])) :
                $total_quantity += $product['quantity'];
            endif;

        endforeach;

        foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product) :
            if (has_term('nettoyage', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'])) :
                if ($total_quantity < $minimum_cart_product_total && $i == 0) {
                    wc_add_notice(
                        sprintf(
                            '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required from the nettoyage category before checking out.</strong>'
                                . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                            $minimum_cart_product_total,
                            $total_quantity
                        ),
                        'error'
                    );
                }
                $i++;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    }
}
```